# Find vector3 in a direction but with a given magnitude

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get the direction by subtraction of two vector3. In this case my gameObject and my mouse position.

```
Vector3 dir = gameObject.transform.position -
orthoCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition)
```

I now want to place an object in the same direction but at a limited distance from my original gameobject. That is I need a vector in the same direction but with a magnitude of 0.5. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var posn = gameObject.transform.position - (dir.normalized * desiredDistance);
```

Hopefully this doesn't sound too condescending, but you change a vector's magnitude by multiplying it with a scalar.

Comment: what is desired distance here  - the magnitude(float) ? or a Vector3 ?

Comment: Why are you subtracting the direction?  and yes Sameer it would be your 0.5 value

Comment: to get the direction from me to my target it is (target - me)  this gives me a vector from me to my target.  to place an object half a unit in that direction would be: `me + (dir * desiredDistance)`  as subtracting it would put it in the opposite direction.

Comment: I used the `-` because it gave a distance from the object to the observer.  If you specifically want the displacement to originate from the observer then the starting point must also change, `var posn = orthoCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) + (dir.normalized *desiredDistance);`

Comment: The key point here being that the answer to the actual question is that Vectors can be multiplied with scalars (float, double, int, long) to 'resize' them

Comment: OP is correct in that he's finding the direction from camera (well, image plane) to object. I was just being lazy =)